# How to Implement Dark Mode Theme in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Android Q launched by Google, Dark Theme was released with it. Dark Mode applies to both the system UI and the apps running in it.

I want to implement this feature to application, any good suggestions ?

Help will be appreciated !

Comment: Refer to the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you import the latest version of the google material library
`com.google.android.material:material:version.latest`

Then you can set your apps theme to `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight....`

This will switch your UI to a dark theme variant when the user toggles it in their system

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme

Answer (score 0):

In order to support Dark theme, you must set your app's theme (usually found in res/values/styles.xml) to inherit from a DayNight theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
```

[for more information](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme)